# How do I input values from a file into a vector?

Tags: c++

I've been having trouble with this bit of code for a while now.

```
void readData(const string & filename, vector<double> & fpAngle, vector<double> & liftCo) {

ifstream inFS(filename);
double num1;
double num2;

inFS.open(filename);

if (!inFS.is_open()) {
    cout << "Error opening " << filename << endl;
    exit (1);
}

while (inFS >> num1 >> num2) {
    if (!inFS.fail()) {
        fpAngle.push_back (num1);
        liftCo.push_back (num2);
    }
}

inFS.close();

return;
```

For this situation I am extracting values from a file that are formatted into 2 columns and I have to store both columns into their respective vectors. No matter what I try, I can never get the correct amount of values into both vectors. Is there something I'm missing here? Thanks.

Edit: The problem has been solved. I took moldbdnilo's suggestion and edited the code accordingly, removing open/close as well as (!infs.fail()) which got the code to work. Thank you, and apologies for possibly not being more thorough about my question.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. First of all please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and then learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I also recommend that you take some time to [learn how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). Furthermore, please edit your question to show us some examples of the file you attempt to read.

Comment: You don't need the `open`– the file is opened by the constructor that takes a file path. `if (!inFS.fail())` is unnecessary: if the condition were false you would have exited the loop. You also don't need to `close`, the destructor does that for you. I recommend a review of the chapter on files and streams in your favourite book.

Comment: I suspect that your stream enters an error state because you attempt to open it twice.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you with couple of changes.

```
int main()
{

    ifstream inFile;
    inFile.open(filename);
    if (inFile.fail()) {
         cout << "Error opening " << filename << endl;
    }
   std::vector<std::string> code;
    string S;
   while(fh>>s){
             code.push_back(s);
    }

    for(int i=0; i<vs.size(); i++){

            std::cout<<code[i]<<std::endl;
    }
}
```